# Convert PNG image to SVG / Vector 

Tags: vector, svg, inkscape

We are desperate to convert an image so that it can be used as an image map. Everything I have tried, really doesnt cut the mustard. I havent the experience to work at very high resolutions.. plus I dont know the terminology and neither have the skills or resources to invest in learning how to do this, knowing many others on here and the internet have far greater experience.

I have downloaded and played with Inkscape, but really am going round in circles...

So thought I would ask here.

What I am after is similar to Raphael Australia Map or David Lynchs, http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

No frills, no effects, just change the state color of the map on hover and retain that event on click.

Here is what we have ...

What we have is a MAP like this.
[image]

We lost the original file, which was pure gray. I have this left :(

Anyway, we want it so that each state ( including the territory ACT ) not indicated on the above map, represented in pink #ec008c . On hover

Map needs to be FLAWLESS !! Also require that any imagery must be png and transparent bg.

Must remain exact size as above. Must be extremely accurate on svg coordinates, and optionally would like the STATE text to appear , like the QLD is shown on the image above, but not wholly necessary.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried *Path > Trace Bitmap* in Inkscape? If you play with the settings you should be able to get a decent vectorised image.

Comment: Thanks Peter, the issue is I have no idea how to isolate the different australian states, and then add different color for the hover states, using vectors.. its way over my head.

Comment: After tracing the bitmap, you can use Path > Break Apart, which should isolate the states (I tried and NSW and Victoria remained together). I guess you'll have to add ACT manually.

Comment: For the hover effect add   <style>path:hover{fill: #ec008c;}</style> somewhere within the SVG tags.

Comment: Peter you are the MAN ! Just need to do ACT ( Australian Capital Territory ) I can redo the graphic to include this if it makes it easier, absolutely just what we are after. Have messaged you also. Cheers Ste

Answer (score 4):

Vectorised:

EPS:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13402937/Australia.eps

Adobe Illustrator:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13402937/Australia.ai

Comment: Maybe you could explain how you vectorised this... "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for life."

Comment: I used a program called vector magic. There is a free online version available on their site but i'm not sure if you can export from the online one.

Comment: Hey thanks. Ok now as PlanPlan said, I aint a fisherman ... and it is friday and fish on friday lol, but how do I now export this to get the co-ordinates for each state etc. Will check out that site .

Answer (score 1):

try to use this tool, its the potrace part to trace pixelpictures in inkscape with many features. [potrace traces pictures from commandline](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I have obtained extraordinary results with https://vectormagic.com/ , which can be tried online.